# Synchronize Print When Expression & Text Field Expression

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

**Background**

The **Totals** section in the image below shows strange results for the **Trend** column. The text should be **true** when the value under the column named *Previous* equals the value under the column named *Current*.

[image]

**Print When Expression & Text Field Expression**

The expressions are evaluated using identical code:

```
new java.lang.Boolean(
    $V{LAST_WEEK_TALLY_0}.add(
    $V{LAST_WEEK_TALLY_1} ).add(
    $V{LAST_WEEK_TALLY_2} ).add(
    $V{LAST_WEEK_TALLY_3} ).longValue() ==
    $V{THIS_WEEK_TALLY_0}.add(
    $V{THIS_WEEK_TALLY_1} ).add(
    $V{THIS_WEEK_TALLY_2} ).add(
    $V{THIS_WEEK_TALLY_3} ).longValue()
)
```

The *Evalutation Time* for the Text Field is set to *Band*.

**Problem**

It appears as though the *Print When Expression* code is being evaluated for the values under the *Previous* and *Current* columns one row too late. The value being printed is correct for that row. This means that the evaluation time for *Print When Expression* and *Text Field Expression* are not evaluating at the same time.

**Question**

What do I need to do to make *Print When Expression* and *Text Field Expression* evaluate to the same result at the same time? This would then produce the word **true** for the **Totals'** *Trend* column whenever *`Previous == Current`*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An inelegant, but functional solution is to merge the static text fields together, and avoid having to synchronize *Print When Expression* and *Text Field Expression* in favour of just the latter.

```
($V{LAST_WEEK_TALLY_0}.add(
  $V{LAST_WEEK_TALLY_1} ).add(
  $V{LAST_WEEK_TALLY_2} ).add(
  $V{LAST_WEEK_TALLY_3} ).longValue() ==
$V{THIS_WEEK_TALLY_0}.add(
  $V{THIS_WEEK_TALLY_1} ).add(
  $V{THIS_WEEK_TALLY_2} ).add(
  $V{THIS_WEEK_TALLY_3} ).longValue()) ? "-" :
($V{LAST_WEEK_TALLY_0}.add(
  $V{LAST_WEEK_TALLY_1} ).add(
  $V{LAST_WEEK_TALLY_2} ).add(
  $V{LAST_WEEK_TALLY_3} ).longValue() <
$V{THIS_WEEK_TALLY_0}.add(
  $V{THIS_WEEK_TALLY_1} ).add(
  $V{THIS_WEEK_TALLY_2} ).add(
  $V{THIS_WEEK_TALLY_3} ).longValue()) ? "Up" : "Down"
```

Answer (score 1):

I have two suggestions, not sure if either will work:

**1. Using summation from iReport**
Assuming you are using cross table, there is a feature to sum the total on the row or on the column. Make Previous Total, equal to the number of Previous Totals, and same goes for Current Total.
Then in Trend column, write an expression like  `Current_Value - Previous_value ==0`

**2. Find the sums in Query**
This is the more robust solution, maybe a little more complicated though. I usually don't rely much on iReport, and always give it ready data.
If you generate your report data in Java, it will be easy to fill in all the values before calling the report.

Comment: Finding the sums in the query would be difficult. Because of the nature of the data, I could not easily use a crosstab report. Thanks for the response!